# Adding a scope through an association join table in Rails 4

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Lets say I want to organize some books and dedicate a shelf to each Author, but each Author has many books. I would like to create a join table which will give me access to the author belonging to a shelf and the first book on that shelf. To give you an idea of how it is set up:

```
class Shelf < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shelf
    has_many :books
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
end
```

At the moment, I have something like this: `Shelf.includes(author: :books)`, but that will include all of the books that the author has.

When I call `books` on each object, I would like for it to spit out one book object (the first book).

I have read that I should use merge, like `Shelf.includes(author: :books).merge(Book.first)`, but have had no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems odd that Shelf belongs to Author and the reverse is also true. Usually you see `belongs_to` and `has_many` pairs.

Comment: I think the shelf must contain `has_many :author`

Comment: Reading the description it should rather be `has_one :author`.

Comment: Does it really matter if a shelf is dedicated to one author? The names of the models don't really matter, it doesn't change the problem.

Comment: If the has/belongs to declarations don't match the underlying schema then it could affect your results.